# Disable drag of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, drag

I want to ask how to make frame can not drag when the application is running?

And then how to disable maximize, minimize button (title bar)?

I'm using `JFrame`.

Comment: This description sounds more like a tool-tip.  What is the benefit to the end user of breaking a frame like that?

Comment: You can't (really).  These are look and feel/platform specific operations.  You could use a `JDialog` instead, as this typically only has a close button.  You could also try overriding the `setBounds` method of the frame and make sure that it always at a specific location

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below line it removes the window decorations like close maximise and minimise(titlebar). This itself disables the dragging only with mouse events.

```
frame.setUndecorated(true);
```

Comment: *"This itself disables the dragging"*  But it does not prevent the window being moved.  Alt+space on Windows pops a menu that allows me to reposition the undecorated window using arrow keys.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a `JWindow` instead of a `JFrame`.  There is no title bar, so the user won't be able to move it.

```
setResizable(false);
setUndecorated(true);
getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.PLAIN_DIALOG);
```

Comment: *"..the user won't be able to move it."*  I can.  Alt+space on Windows pops a menu that allows me to reposition the window using arrow keys.

Comment: Gnome allows to move windows by `Alt+mouse_drag` at any part of the window.