# How to make a JFrame not movable?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog, jwindow

#### The problem

I would like to know whether it is possible to make a `JFrame` not movable/draggable - just out of curiosity and not for a real use case. The problem is that the window manager of the operating system is responsible for the appearance of the windows, but the program itself has only a few possible settings. This is why I am looking for a hack.

#### What I have tried

- removed the decoration of the `JFrame` as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13468058/8292104) answer (however, it is still possible to move the window, e.g. by holding the ALT key on GNU/Linux)
- set a `ComponentListener` which resets the position if the `JFrame` is moved (however, this looks very glitchy since the listener only reacts **after** the dragging, but the `JFrame` should **always** stay at the same position)
- created a full screen `JFrame`, made it transparent and added a `JPanel` to simulate a window (however, one can still drag the window, even if it is maximized)
- used a `JWindow` and a `JDialog` instead (also does not work)

Is there any way to achieve the desired behavior by using a different approach or improving one of my approaches?

Comment: Did you consider a splash screen?

Comment: If there is a hack it's going to be found in some kind of native solution. Java / Swing is too high level an abstraction.

Comment: @MarsAtomic are you referring to the selected answer, that is ops second suggestion?

Comment: @matt Isn't a splash screen also a JFrame or JWindow?

Comment: @Mars Atomic This solution has the same problems as the solution using a listener. It is glitchy.

Comment: If you check the demo, it is not movable on linux. I don't know what it is and I haven't dug into th source to look. Maybe there is a solution buried in there. Since you have to start it with a -splash argument it might take a bit more work. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Comment: @matt I looked at the demo, but to me it seems as if one cannot add any components to the splash screen and only draw using Graphics. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void formComponentMoved(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {                                    
       this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }     

addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
                public void componentMoved(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
                    formComponentMoved(evt);
                }
            });
```

Works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is also very glitchy and it only moves the window back after you release the mouse. But the window always has to stay at the same location.

Comment: Almost there, better if you used to return like a false, on the father method.