# Make JFrame undraggable in Windows

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I would like to make a JFrame undraggable (The user cannot move the window when click on the title bar and move the mouse).

Is it possible to do that in Windows?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    
    public Test() {
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

I'm using Java 11 on Windows 10.

Comment: *I would like to make a JFrame undraggable* Why? It is the users desktop. Let the user control how the windows are positioned. If you are trying to cover the desktop with your own app it won't work because the user can simply toggle to other apps by using Alt+Tab. You could use the default Metal LAF and then remove the MouseMotionListener from the frame.

Comment: Don't use setSize(). The point of the `setExtendedState()` method is to do that for you. Also, the resizeable method should be invoke before the frame is visible and before setting the state.

Comment: @camickr This doesn't solve the problem when the user double click on the title bar.

Comment: A click is handled by a MouseListener, so also remove the MouseListener. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I've edited my question. I don't have a mouse listener. It's a very simple JFrame.

Comment: You were asked why you are trying to do this and haven't given a reason. This is NOT something that can be done using Java since the dragging is controlled by the OS frame peer component. See George's answer below. So the question is why do you think you need to do this. If it is that important then I gave you a suggestion on what you need to do. You need to use the Metal L&F because it uses an undecorated frame and creates it own custom title bar and borders. Then you can remove the mouse listeners it uses to implement the dragging logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You can't

Because the `setBounds` of a frame happens on frame peer. Check the [WFramePeer](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/windows/classes/sun/awt/windows/WFramePeer.java) code.

First, the class is package private. You cant `@Override` it and decorate `setWhateverBounds` methods.

Secondly, there is a lot of `native` methods.

## Your only hope,

might be to use `frame.setUndecorated(true)` and create your own title bar without dragging functionality. But good luck on giving this title bar the native UI style.

Answer (score 0):

From [another stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48812248) question:-

Add this to your code

```
private void formComponentMoved(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {                                    
       this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }     

frame.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
                public void componentMoved(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
                    formComponentMoved(evt);
                    frame.setLocation(frame.getX(),frame.getY());
                }
            });
```

Comment: The window here moves but goes back again after the mouse is released. It's not a professional solution but thank you for your try I really appreciate it.

Comment: @BuSaeed I have edited the question. Now paste this code. Tested Code.