# How to make a jframe window stable on the screen, that is, can't be dragged or moved?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

For example the game window I made is 600*800, I want to "immobilize" it on the screen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable drag of JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467997/disable-drag-of-jframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a [full screen window](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#setFullScreenWindow%28java.awt.Window%29):

```
JFrame frame = /* ... */;

frame.setUndecorated(true);

GraphicsEnvironment env =
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice screen = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
screen.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
```